# Tensorly and tensor rank (CP rank)

Tags: tensor, rank, tensorly

I am trying to compute the tensor rank aka CP rank (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition#Tensor_rank) for a specific sparse tensor that is 8 x 8 x 8.

I am new to Tensorly and have only just installed. After reading the documentation on the parafac function (http://tensorly.org/stable/modules/generated/tensorly.decomposition.parafac.html), it seems I need to specify a particular tensor rank in order to find a tensor rank decomposition of that particular rank. How can one compute the tensor rank using this software? Is there perhaps a different function which yields the tensor rank when given a specific tensor?

Answer (score 0):

Determining the rank of a tensor is, in general, NP-hard. Typically, the CP decomposition takes a tensor and the desired rank as input.

If you use the latest version of TensorLy from Github, you can set `rank='same'` or any floating value between 0 and 1 to set the rank so as to keep either the same number of parameters as the original tensor, or a fraction of the parameters.